# Set # of attempts according to Completed Date - Postgres SQL, Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a select statement which return below table (*User_Result)*.

```
userId   UserName   Course  EnrolmentDate CompletedDate   Status
111      User_01    Course1  2016-03-16   2016-03-18       Fail
111      User_01    Course1  2016-03-20   2016-03-24       pass
112      User_02    Course2  2016-01-05   2016-01-05       Fail
112      User_02    Course2  2016-01-05   2016-01-06       Fail
112      User_02    Course2  2016-01-20   2016-01-25       Pass
```

Now I want to add number of attempts on those users according to there enrolment date and completed date.

How I did is;

```
With "report_result" AS
(
SELECT
 "userID",
 "UserName",
 "Course",
 "EnrolmentDate",
 "Completed Date",
 "status"
FROM "User_Result"
)
,
"attempts_tbl" AS (
        SELECT
            "userID",
             "Course",
            count(1) AS attempt
        FROM report_result
        GROUP BY "userID", "Course"
)
,
"finaltable" AS
(
Select
report_result.*,
attempts_tbl.attempt
from
report_result,attempts_tbl
where report_result."userID" = attempts_tbl."userID" and report_result."Course" = attempts_tbl."Course"
)

SELECT *
FROM final table;
```

But I got below result,

```
userId   UserName   Course  EnrolmentDate CompletedDate   Status    #Attempts
    111      User_01    Course1  2016-03-16   2016-03-18       Fail     2
    111      User_01    Course1  2016-03-20   2016-03-24       pass     2
    112      User_02    Course2  2016-01-05   2016-01-05       Fail     3
    112      User_02    Course2  2016-01-05   2016-01-06       Fail     3
    112      User_02    Course2  2016-01-20   2016-01-25       Pass     3
```

How should I get # of attempts according to this:

```
userId   UserName   Course  EnrolmentDate CompletedDate   Status    #Attempts
    111      User_01    Course1  2016-03-16   2016-03-18       Fail     1
    111      User_01    Course1  2016-03-20   2016-03-24       pass     2
    112      User_02    Course2  2016-01-05   2016-01-05       Fail     1
    112      User_02    Course2  2016-01-05   2016-01-06       Fail     2
    112      User_02    Course2  2016-01-20   2016-01-25       Pass     3
```

Mush appreciate your replies.

Thank you
:)

Comment: do you want #attempts to be a rolling sum?

Comment: I want to get attempt by 1, 2, 3 for each record as I shown on my last table.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `row_number` function here.

```
select u.*, 
row_number() over(partition by userid,course order by enrollmentdate,completeddate) as attempts
from "User_Result" u
```

Comment: Ohh.. I totally forgot it.. my brain is shutting down now. Thanks @vkp. Much appreciate it. Good Day !!